# Are skill magazines cumulative?

Tags: fallout-new-vegas

Are the effects granted by skill magazines cumulative? By that, I mean, if I read two of the same magazine, do I get +20 (+40 with the Comprehension perk, which I have) as my skill bonus?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. However, as with chems, the durations stack, so if you read 2 mags at a time, they will last twice as long.